# WiX Property: Directory Search: "Could not access network location"

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I'm making an installer with the WiX 3.5 toolset, and I've run across a problem:

The installer needs to be able to detect whether another program is present, and if so, add a DLL file in its directory. I use the following code to figure out where the second program is installed:

```
<Property Id="FIND_INSTALLDIR" Value="[%ProgramFilesFolder]\PROGRAM">
    <RegistrySearch
        Id="INSTALLDIRSearch"
        Root="HKLM"
        Name="UninstallString"
        Type="file"
        Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\PROGRAM"
    />
</Property>
```

The trouble is, if the second program *isn't* installed, Windows Installer gives me an error:

```
Could not access network location [%ProgramFilesFolder]\PROGRAM
```

I need to be able to handle this gracefully, though... how do I recover from the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Cosmin's help, I found the solution:

All I had to do is to **not** set `Value`, so that it wouldn't try to find the folder... everything else worked perfectly!

Comment: right, you can't use `[variables]` in `<Property Value`. But you can set the default by adding another `<SetProperty Id="FIND_INSTALLDIR" Value="[%ProgramFilesFolder]\PROGRAM">not FIND_INSTALLDIR</SetProperty>`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will help you:
[Detecting the presence of a directory at install time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937674/wix-detecting-the-presence-of-a-directory-at-install-time/4942333#4942333)

Basically, you need to make sure that the property you are using for the DLL folder is set to a valid path, even if the DLL will not be installed (the actual path was not found).

Comment: Hm... yeah I'll try that, I'm not sure if it'll help but it looks nice. Thanks.

Comment: Huh -- the link helped, but not in the way you mentioned. :) All I had to do is to *not* set `Value`... everything else worked perfectly!

Comment: +1 because this helped me, but since it wasn't the solution, I can't really accept the answer. Thanks though! :)